# can I import two python classes like this?

Tags: python

I have two the python classes.  I wonder if I can do something like

file A

```
# file A.py
from B import B
class A(){
    def Foo():
        pass

}
```

file B

```
# file B.py
from A import A
class B(){
    def Bar():
        pass

}
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to get mutually recursive imports to work? Providing real code (i.e. not with braces) might help clarify.

Comment: "I wonder", did you actually try your code? Please try your code and provide errors if there are

Comment: Python doesn't forbid circular imports but it's best to avoid them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, however, you might be better advised to use different names for the files and the classes they contain.

Please note that the use of `{}` is not a python construct to mark scope boundaries

#### file a.py

```
# file a.py
from b import B
class A()
    def Foo():
        pass
```

#### file b.py

```
# file b.py
from a import A
class B()
    def Bar():
        pass
```

This type of circular import will work, but there are better ways, notably placing imports in an `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Cross reference can be achieve by local import. See below example

File A:

```
# file A.py
from B import B
class A():
    def Foo():
        pass
```

File B:

```
# file B.py
class B():
    def Bar():
        pass

def some_function():
    from A import A
    # use A here
```